# Pass url anchor from javascript variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying to get the url of the current page along with the number after #. I am useing this to get the #number: `var hash = window.location.hash;`. But i want to pass it to a php variable. I used cookies to take the variable from javascript and pass it to php but my webpage remains 2 steps back till echo the value. What other possibilites I have to pass a variable to php. Below is the code i used.

```
<script>
var hash = window.location.hash;
document.cookie="hash="+hash;
</script>

<?php
$hash='';
if(isset($_COOKIE['hash']))
$hash=$_COOKIE['hash'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround

```
<script>
var url = location.href.split('#');  // or location.hash.split("#")
document.cookies = "fragment = " + url[1];
if(url[1] != "<?php echo $_COOKIE['fragment']; ?>"){ // or if(url[1] != ""){
    window.location.reload()
}
</script>

<?php echo $_COOKIE["fragment"]; ?>
```